# Animate rotation to the nearest value in React Native

Tags: react-native

Given, interpolation, that has to rotate a car marker:

```
this.rotation.interpolate({
  inputRange: [0, 360],
  outputRange: ['0deg', '360deg'],
  extrapolate: 'clamp'
})
```

GIF below represents the following bearings:

```
1. 337.38055647641903
2. 335.202973299875
3. 13.03761189748721
4. 13.042704554861551
5. 358.77805501498045
```

[image]

Green line is how I want it to work (rotate to the nearest value). Red line is how it works currently (on GIF).

[image]

Is there a way to animate rotation to the nearest value? (in our case from 335 to 13 clockwise). Maybe there's a better way instead of interpolation?

Comment: Hey, Did you manage to find anything on this?

Answer (score 0):

```
let heading = this.state.heading;
    let oldHeading = this.state.oldHeading;
    const duration = 200;
    if (oldHeading - heading > 180) {
        Animated.timing(
            this.state.spinAnim,
        { 
            toValue: 360,
            duration: duration,
            easing: Easing.linear,
            useNativeDriver: true
        }).start(() => this.state.spinAnim.setValue(0));
    } else if (oldHeading - heading < -180) {
        Animated.timing(
            this.state.spinAnim,
        { 
            toValue: 0,
            duration: duration,
            easing: Easing.linear,
            useNativeDriver: true
        }).start(() => this.state.spinAnim.setValue(360));
    } else {
        Animated.timing(
            this.state.spinAnim,
        { 
            toValue: heading,
            duration: duration,
            easing: Easing.linear,
            useNativeDriver: true
        }).start();
    }
```

I had the same problem so my solution was to keep every time the exactly previous heading and if the distance is bigger than 180 i use two separate animations. One that animates from x to 0 and then sets value to 360 (or x to 360 and then sets value to 0) and the one that is the "default" and runs every time.

Answer (score 0):

This is equivalent to avoiding rollbacks in CSS rotate transitions.

A way to do this is to recalculate the next angle based on the amplitude of the previous one. You still have to use interpolation, what changes is that the value fed to the animation will be the result of this function ([credits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53416030/8042204)), which adds the difference to the previous value and performs some modulo checks to guess the closest value:

```js
function closestEquivalentAngle(from, to) {
    var delta = ((((to - from) % 360) + 540) % 360) - 180;
    return from + delta;
}
```

So for example, next time you move forward from 335 deg to 13 deg, the result will be 373, that is the original value plus a difference of 38 degrees. That works backwards as well. Just remember to store the value of the resulting angle somewhere, so you can use it on the next iteration as `prevAngle`.

Pulling it all together:

```js
const RotateComp = (props) => {
  const rotationValue = React.useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

  // Animation interpolation
  const rotation = rotationValue.interpolate({
    inputRange: [-360, 360],
    outputRange: ['-360deg', '360deg'],
  });

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Obtain prevAngle and nextAngle, then...

    Animated.timing(
      rotationValue,
      {
        toValue: closestEquivalentAngle(prevAngle, nextAngle),
        duration: 200,
        useNativeDriver: true,
      },
    ).start();
  }, [rotationValue])

  return (
    // ...
    <Animated.View
      style={{
        ...props.style,
        transform: [{rotate: rotation}],
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </Animated.View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Don't know why someone downvoted you, because your answer goes a long way in the right direction. I was struggling to get it working but having the angles from -360 to 360 did work well. Thanks!